# Any way to remove default switches with which chromedriver opens chromebrowser via .net bindings?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to remove the default switches runtime with which chromdriver opens chromebrowser from .net bindings. 
http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome_launcher.cc     line:112

Also i see that we have the option to remove the default switches by using capabilities in chromedriver server.
refer : line 119

But there is not way to pass this from .net bindings..?

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=570 & https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=641 were raised requesting the same.

Comment: We are trying to test an extension on ChromeBrowser. But as the extension is not hosted on store as of now, when chromedriver pass "disable-default-apps" switch to the chromebrowser, these extensions are removed from the browser instance opened.

Comment: yes.. i agree,but that wouldn't suit our way of testing as we install extensions runtime and we wouldn't know their unique extension id prior.